# Regex to find String which starts with ABC and not ends with XYZ

Tags: regex

Please help me here

For below example how do I write the regex to find string which starts with ABC and not ends with XYZ

Example:

```
ABCfdsAFfadsXYZ ABCffasdffdaAAA FASfdaaffasaAFA
```

Out of these, only the second one should match.

Comment: Hi Smith, and welcome. It's not so bad for tag [tag:regex] but please show us what you've tried next time.

Answer (score 5):

```
\bABC\w*\b(?<!XYZ)
```

assuming your regex engine supports lookbehind assertions.

**Explanation:**

```
\b        # Start at a word boundary
ABC       # Match ABC
\w*       # Match any number of alphanumeric characters
\b        # End at a word boundary
(?<!XYZ)  # Assert that the previous three characters were not XYZ
```

Comment: Exactly. :) Everything's fine, isn't it?

Comment: Smith, don't forget to hit the accept button (`V`) if Tim has answered your question.